# GROUP first and second level friends

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

Lets say that given a song_id and a uid, we would like to know all friends (direct friends and friends of frinds) that like the same song:

This is how we are doing it:

```
public function get_song_mates($uid, $song_id, $current_only = true, $limit = PHP_INT_MAX)
    {

        $sql    = "SELECT * 
                    FROM (
                    (
                        SELECT users . * ,  '1st' AS  `level`, 1 AS `level_i` 
                        FROM songs
                        JOIN users ON users.id = songs.user_id
                        JOIN friends AS my_friend ON my_friend.fid = users.id 
                        AND my_friend.uid = '".$uid."'                  
                        WHERE song_id =  '".$song_id."')
                    UNION (

                    SELECT second_friend . * ,  '2nd' AS  `level`, 2 AS `level_i`
                    FROM songs
                    JOIN users AS second_friend ON second_friend.id = songs.user_id
                    JOIN friends ON friends.uid = second_friend.id
                    JOIN users AS first_friend ON first_friend.id = friends.fid 
                    JOIN friends AS my_friend ON my_friend.fid = first_friend.id 
                    AND my_friend.uid = '".$uid."'                  
                    WHERE song_id =  '".$song_id."'


                    AND second_friend.id NOT IN
                        (
                            SELECT users.id 
                              FROM songs
                              JOIN users ON users.id = songs.user_id
                              JOIN friends AS my_friend ON my_friend.fid = users.id 
                               AND my_friend.uid = '".$uid."'
                             WHERE song_id = '".$song_id."'
                        )
                    ) ORDER BY `level_i` ASC, firstname, lastname
                    ) AS friend                 
                    GROUP BY id ORDER BY `level_i`";

        $users  = $this->getFromSql($sql);  
        return $users;
    }
```

But please note we had to add:

```
AND second_friend.id NOT IN...
```

to prevent showing same user as direct friend and as a friend of friend.. i am pretty sure i need to make use of GROUP BY, but i just can't get with the right syntax. any clue here?

-EDIT-

```
friends(uid, fid)
songs(id, user_id, song_id)
users(id, frist_name, last_name)
```

Comment: Can you describe the tables especially the FOREIGN KEYS?

Comment: Using string concatention to generate SQL? Ever heard of SQL Injection?

Comment: It is best to reduce a problem presented on SO to bare essentials.  The bare essentials here are the SQL and not the PHP wrapper.  The current job part is also not crucial to the question.  As it is, the SQL is unreadable because it is tied up in PHP.  Also, beware [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327)!

Comment: edited with relevant database tables and rows. basically we have the last AND NOT IN to remove the friends of friends of mine that are also direct friends of mine. so we don't show duplicated users. any hint would be very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it like this:

public function get_song_mates($uid, $song_id, $current_only = true, $limit = PHP_INT_MAX)
    {

```
    $sql    = "SELECT DISTINCT * 
                FROM (
                (
                    SELECT users . * ,  '1st' AS  `level`, 1 AS `level_i` 
                    FROM songs
                    JOIN users ON users.id = songs.user_id
                    JOIN friends AS my_friend ON my_friend.fid = users.id 
                    AND my_friend.uid = '".$uid."'                  
                    WHERE song_id =  '".$song_id."')
                UNION (

                SELECT DISTINCT second_friend . * ,  '2nd' AS  `level`, 2 AS `level_i`
                FROM songs
                JOIN users AS second_friend ON second_friend.id = songs.user_id
                JOIN friends ON friends.uid = second_friend.id
                JOIN users AS first_friend ON first_friend.id = friends.fid 
                JOIN friends AS my_friend ON my_friend.fid = first_friend.id 
                AND my_friend.uid = '".$uid."'                  
                WHERE song_id =  '".$song_id."'";

    $users  = $this->getFromSql($sql);  
    return $users;
}
```